# Flexbox items don't wrap in latest Safari and Chrome (using max-width on flex-container and flex-basis on flex-items)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

There's a plethora of questions relating to issues of the implementation of flexbox in Safari, but I couldn't find a solution that addresses my issue. Following code is working great in Firefox: both images are displayed in a row if there's enough space, otherwise the second image wraps below the first one. In Safari and Chrome, the second image wraps into a new line, no matter how much space available. Also, theres a huge vertical gap between the stacked images:

```css
div {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 42em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

img {
  max-width: 25em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  -webkit-flex-basis: 14em;
  flex-basis: 14em;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div style="">
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/480/320">
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/480/320">
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/madamadam/ywkrxLv0/25/

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: In my Chrome, the images are on separate lines, no matter how much space is available.

Comment: can you please replace max-width: fit-content; instead of using max-width: 42em;

Comment: @Gerard You are right! Will edit original question.

Comment: @MehediHasanSiam wrapping and scaling behavior then is not consistent over different browsers: in Safari, the images don't scale at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the issue is related to the initial image width that is considered to perform the calculation of the free space. Adding `width:0` seems to fix the issue

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 42em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

img {
  max-width: 25em;
  width:0; 
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  flex-basis: 14em;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div style="">
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/480/320">
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/480/320">
</div>
```